# How to drop/delete/filter rows in pandas dataframe based on string pattern condition?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

Say there's a data frame with (4000,13) shape. Say dataframe["str_labels"] may has "|" value in it.
How to sort pandas dataframe based on removing any rows (all 13 columns) consisting of string value "|".
example:

```
list(dataframe["str_labels"])=["abcd","aaa","op|gg","iku | gv"]
filtered_out = ["abcd", "aaa"]
```

```
## example code
dataframe["|" not in dataframe["str_labels"]]
# or
dataframe[dataframe["str_Labels"].str.contains("|")]
# ........etc
```

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: It means some input data, and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a list of characters that are the conditions for dropping rows:

```
list = ['<character>', '\|',....]
```

and then filter your `df` by

```
df = df[~df['your column'].isin(['list'])]
```

Note the `\|` for the pipe character.

Comment: For any other string it's working but not for "|". why so?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. For pipe character | you need in your list to give ´\|'